# Responsive content with font-awsome and VueJs 3

Tags: css, vue.js, responsive-design, vuejs3, font-awesome

I want to change the style of my component to fit the content,
My component `Plan.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="plan">
    <div id="planFlex">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-user fa-xl" />
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-arrow-left fa-xl" />
      <h1>Plan</h1>
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-arrow-right fa-xl" />
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-robot fa-xl" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Plan"
  };
</script>

<style>
@import "../css/Plan.css";
</style>
```

my stylesheet `Plan.css`:

```css
#planFlex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fa-user {
  color: white;
}

.fa-robot {
  color: white;
}

.fa-arrow-right {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.fa-arrow-left {
  color: white;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

#planFlex h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  color: antiquewhite;
}

#planFlex h1:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#planFlex h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  color: white;
}
```

I have tried to add `flex-shrink: 1`, and `width: fit-content` to my stylesheet, but it didn't work well with me, can you please tell me how can I make my design responsive? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `.plan` outer div which by default will display as block, making your `#planFlex` stretch to its borders.

If you add the following you should find that `#planFlex` will just be the width of your content:

```css
.plan {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

In your specific case, you should consider removing the 80px padding on your arrow icons and let flex do the spacing for you. Assuming you want the icons to stick to the sides and your title right in the middle, just wrapped them around in some div, that did the trick for me running your project:

```html
 <div id="planFlex">
  <div>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-user fa-xl"></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left fa-xl"></i>
  </div>
  <h1 @click="addPopUp(testPopup, `Lego not in the right place`)">Plan</h1>
  <div>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right fa-xl"></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-robot fa-xl"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/clW4hxx.png) the problem is still unresolved, the user icon is outside the border, you can see the full code [here](https://gricad-gitlab.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/pacbot_group/GUI_pacbot/-/blob/devel/src)

Comment: I see, thanks for sharing the full code, I've updated my answer accordingly.